# R select specific length from a sequence

Tags: r

Say I have a sequence from 1 to (a+b)*q, I would like to select the 1st "a" elements and skip the following "b" elements and repeat.
For example

```r
a = 5; b = 4; q = 3
seq(1, (a+b)*q)
1:27
a <- c(1:5, 10:14, 19:23)
```

For sequences > 1000, it is hard to do it manually, so is there a way to with a code?

Comment: create a matrix and slice off the unwanted `c(matrix(seq(1, (a + b) * q), a + b)[1:a, ])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can take advantage of "recycling" of arguments/indices:

```r
seq(1, (a+b)*q)[c(rep(TRUE,5),rep(FALSE,4))]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5 10 11 12 13 14 19 20 21 22 23
```

Recycling here means that the indices are of length 9, but the vector itself is length 27, a multiple of 9. This means that the 9 indices are repeated three times consecutively.

When it is not a clear multiple, though, R may not tell you anything. Let's change the "4" to a "3", where length 8 does not go evenly into 27:

```r
seq(1, (a+b)*q)[c(rep(TRUE,5),rep(FALSE,3))]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  9 10 11 12 13 17 18 19 20 21 25 26 27
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --------
#          len5     gap3    len5   gap3   len5    gap3  len3
```

So while the 5/3/5/3/... cycling is consistent, it doesn't necessarily end on a 5. If that's okay, then you're good. If not, you should add in some logical to catch this type of mismatch.